# Choosing the shortest rotation to line up two images

Tags: javascript, css

I have been struggling with this problem for awhile now, even though at first it didn't seem very hard.

Basically I have a triangle on the screen that is being rotated dynamically by javascript.  Each frame of animation, the triangle tries to rotate 1 degree in the "right direction" so that it's tip is pointing at another div on the screen that I can move around with the arrow keys.  This triangle has the following css properties

```
#triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: x;
    top: y;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(degrees)
}
```

I can make the point of the triangle follow the div pretty nicely, except I can't figure out how to make the point always take the shortest rotation. Sometimes it will rotate like 355 degrees in the "wrong" direction, instead of 5 degrees in the right one.

I am kind of stuck.  Can someone please help me out on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
function optimal_angle(degrees) {
  degrees = degrees % 360;

  if (degrees > 180) {
    return degrees - 360;
  } else {
    return degrees;
  }
}
```

And some tests:

```
> optimal_angle(355);
-5
> optimal_angle(-5);
-5
> optimal_angle(124373984);
104
```

If you think about it, the most you can turn in any direction is 180 degrees. So to "optimize" an angle, you remove duplicate revolutions (`degrees % 360`) and if the angle is more than 180 degrees, you turn the other way.